# how to find NTE part numbers

Tags: serial, manufacturing

Can you please tell me how to find part number of the particular chip.

I was trying to find max232 chip locally, and I have been told that I need to provide NTE part number.    I searched google, but could not find proper part number for chip

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NTE has [a search engine](http://nte01.nteinc.com/nte/NTExRefSemiProd.nsf/%24%24Search?OpenForm) for finding part number for their replacement parts.

For the MAX232, it looks like you want NTE7142.